# Tracking a single page AngularJS application with Piwik

Tags: angularjs, matomo

Currently trying to set up Piwik in my application which is a single page AngularJS application.

Even though i have different sub pages which is configured as part of the application, since this is an angular JS application it is considered as one page(entry page is index.html).

My question is if i want to track the navigation to these sub pages from other internal pages in my application, will i be able to track the transitions. **For Example if i have A, B & C as sub pages, i want to know how i reached page B, whether from Page A or page C**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Google search for "Piwik AngularJS": https://www.google.fr/webhp#q=piwik%20angularjs

It yields the following results:

- [Angulartics](http://luisfarzati.github.io/angulartics/)
- [angular-piwik](https://github.com/mike-spainhower/angular-piwik)